# Am trying to fetch YouTube channel Information using the YouTube API but im getting this error. I have tried adding a null checker but it doesn't work

Tags: flutter

Main.dart

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
_loading = true;
_nextPageToken = '';
_scrollController = ScrollController();
_videosList = VideosList(
etag: '', 
nextPageToken: '', 
videos: [], 
kind: '', 
pageInfo: null);
```

This is where the error is. The argument
type 'Null' cant be assigned to 'PageInfo'

```
_videosList.videos = [];
_getChannelInfo();
}
```

Here is my class

```
class VideosList {
VideosList({
required this.kind,
required this.etag,
required this.nextPageToken,     
required this.videos,
required this.pageInfo,
});
```

Comment: Please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

```
_videosList = VideosList(
etag: '', 
nextPageToken: '', 
videos: [], 
kind: '', 
pageInfo: null);
```

You had assigned `null` to the `pageInfo` key, hence the error occurred. Initialize the `pageInfo` with some default value like you had done with other keys. Either this or in VideosList make data type of `pageInfo` nullable like this `String? pageInfo`, then you can set `pageInfo` to `null`.